# Does a closed subset of a metric space have a topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A book I’m using defines the topology of a metric space $M$ as the collection $\tau$ of open subsets of $M$, then goes on to show that this collection is (i) closed under union, (ii) closed under finite intersection, and (iii) contains $\varnothing$ and $M$.

If $S \subseteq M$ is a closed subset of $M$, then the collection of open subsets of $S$ does not contain $S$. Does this mean it’s not possible to define a topology on $S$ in the same way?

Is the error in my thinking here that the collection of open subsets of $S$ must be open *with respect to $S$*? Can you define a topology on $S$ by ignoring the points in $M \cap S^{c}$?

Comment: Yes; it’s sometimes called the [*relative topology*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeTopology.html) or [subspace topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As J.W. Tanner suggested above, given a metric space $(M,d)$ we can take any subset $X \subseteq M$ and define the *relative topology* on $X$ which is given by:

$$
\mathcal{T}_X \;\; =\;\; \{U\cap X \; | \; U \subseteq M \; \text{is open}\}.
$$

One can prove that this is a topology on $X$ since $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{T}_X$ and the properties for union and intersection follow as well.

Comment: Why did you write $X\subset X$?

Comment: That was a typo.  It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

A natural topology to put on $S$ is the *subspace topology*.  The open sets are defined to be the intersections of open sets in $M$ with $S$.  We get $S$ as an open set, since $S=S\cap M$, and $M$ is open in $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The answers you already got are correct, and they apply to any topological space. But because your $M$ was a metric space, there's another way to get the same result. Any subset $X$ of $M$ is also a metric space, just by restricting the metric; that is, the distance in $X$ between any two points of $X$ is defined to be the same as their distance in $M$. [Exercise 1: Check that this is indeed a metric on $X$.] Now that $X$ is a metric space, you can define a topology on it in exactly the same way that a topology was defined on $M$. [Exercise 2: Check that the topology obtained here from the metric on $X$ is the same as the subspace topology defined in the previous answers.]